# How to update a library project code in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, shared-libraries

I have imported 1 of my projects from Eclipse, I also imported the libraries used  with it as standalone projects. The problem is when I update the code on the library module inside my project the library project doesnt update and vice versa. In Eclipse you would update the the library project code and refresh the project so it picks up the changes, how can I achieve the same result in Android Studio??

Comment: Go to this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio

Answer (score -1):

Try adding your library according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio) and then make changes to your library.

Comment: Should detail just a bit more of what actually needs done and not just link to another site.